# Handling PHP sessions

Tags: php, session

I'm a little beginner to PHP and currently doing a project work that involves the task of displaying sessions that are currently live. But, I read in the documentation that sessions were stored in `tmp` folder and will be automatically expired when the browsing session ends. So, what can I do — I also googled and found that it can be **stored in Databases** and then we can get the count?

Was that possible? If so, please give me the methods for that.

Update: Also, please give the way such that entry in the database must be **automatically removed** when the session ends

Comment: What for are you going to use them?

Comment: @Jari To get the total number of open sessions.

Comment: "displaying sessions that are currently live" So you want to display active session (clients that are browsing the website?) 

What you could do is register the ip address with an timestamp of the last visit.

Comment: for some more information on sessions visit this site:http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-PHP-Sessions.html

Comment: You should be aware that there are `sessions` and `sessions`. There is   a construct that lets you save certain stuff, e.g. make the system non-stateless, and yo uhave what in business-logic might be called 'sessions', like users-that-are-online etc. They do not have to be the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you define / let your stakeholders define what information you are after. If it is the technical webserver-number of current active sessions than you can keep on looking at what you are doing, but if you are looking for "number of users on the site" for instance, you should step away from the PHP-concept of sessions. They are something else.

Instead, as saving all this can be somewhat tricky, take a look at the "realtime" functionality on google analytics, maybe that'll be enough.

If that isn't, you need to make a database, register each load and update the loading-time on each action, so you can check out if someone was active during a certain period

Comment: then ignore the fact that the word "sessions" sounds like the `$_SESSION1` stuff, and start thinking of a separate solution.